# css dynamic div width

Tags: html, css, dynamic

I need a div that takes the full width of its parent except when there is an Image in front of it. Because then i want the image to be on the same line. I have tried floating the image to the left which made the text in the div go under the image which I dont want.
Here are some images that i hope will clear up the image:

The thing with the image:

[image: The thing with the image]

The thing without the image:

[image: The thing without the image]

Comment: If you have tried something then please share the code.

Comment: I am sorry i did not know it was obligatory to share the code that i have written myself. I thought it wasnt necessary because nothing i tried seemed to even come close to what i wanted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `display:table` (note: this is **not** using tables for layout)

```css
.wrapper {
  background: lightgray;
  display: table;
}
.wrapper img ~ p {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: top;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <p>
    First Text some Text some Text some Text some Text some Text some Text some Text some Text some Text some Text some Text some Text some Text some Text some Text some Text some Text some Text some Text some Text some Text some Text some Text some Text
    some Text some Text some Text some Text some Text
  </p>
</div>

<div class="wrapper">
  <img src="http://lorempixel.com/300/200" />
  <p>
    First Text some Text some Text some Text some Text some Text some Text some Text some Text some Text some Text some Text some Text some Text some Text some Text some Text some Text some Text some Text some Text some Text some Text some Text some Text
    some Text some Text some Text some Text some Text
  </p>
</div>
```

Comment: This seems to be it. Thank you very much for your time and effort.

Comment: If this is worthy of it you can always accept it by hitting the tick to the left of my answer